# python colored-logs (with other libraries) configuration issue

Tags: python, logging

I'm using I think I'm misunderstanding how to set up a logger instance for [python-coloredlogs](https://github.com/xolox/python-coloredlogs/). It works great until use other libraries with my code, their log messages get output by the root logger and basically I don't want to see them:

```
2016-11-22 13:03:31 <hostname> <app>[66800] INFO some message
2016-11-22 13:03:31 <hostname> requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool[66800] INFO Starting new HTTP connection (1): <...>
```

Afaics the solution should be to create a specific logger for coloredlogs to use, configure it and pass it to coloredlogs `install` method ([code/docstring](https://github.com/xolox/python-coloredlogs/blob/master/coloredlogs/__init__.py#L218)). I do this, but then coloredlogs seems locked to warning log levels only.

I'm probably misunderstanding how to set up a logger instance for coloredlogs correctly.

Using the [python logging howto](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html) example, and adding coloredlogs:

```
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

# test output
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')

import coloredlogs
coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG', logger=logger)
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

outputs:

```
2016-11-16 16:06:53,942 - simple_example - DEBUG - debug message
2016-11-16 16:06:53,942 - simple_example - INFO - info message
2016-11-16 16:06:53,942 - simple_example - WARNING - warn message
2016-11-16 16:06:53,942 - simple_example - ERROR - error message
2016-11-16 16:06:53,942 - simple_example - CRITICAL - critical message
2016-11-16 16:06:53 <hostname> simple_example[63650] WARNING warn message
2016-11-16 16:06:53 <hostname> simple_example[63650] ERROR error message
2016-11-16 16:06:53 <hostname> simple_example[63650] CRITICAL critical message
```

The streamhandler correctly outputs debug level logs, but after coloredlogs is installed the log level is set to warning and info/debug logs are not emitted, even though a) the logger level is set to debug and b) I'm passing in `level='DEBUG'` to `coloredlogs.install` method.

How can I pass in a configured logger to coloredlogs (so that other libraries do log via root logger) and set the coloredlogs level to info/debug?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw that [you posted this question](https://github.com/xolox/python-coloredlogs/issues/18#issuecomment-260989178) directly on the Github issues tracker of `coloredlogs`.

The author of the library answered you, so I am reporting this here.

It seems it was a bug which is fixed since 6.0 version.